# json_encode giving recursion error

Tags: php, ajax, json

```
Warning:  json_encode(): recursion detected in [Directory]
```

What is this error, I can't seem to solve the issue. It's generating a BIG BIG log per error 500 faced. 133,000,000 bytes in size. It's spamming the log till memory max out.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST['type']) && $_REQUEST['type'] = "getmoredetails"){ 
retrievemore($_REQUEST['htmlsource']);
}

function retrievemore($htmlcode){
$retrievetitle = retrievechTitle($htmlcode);
$retrievermb = retrievechRMB($htmlcode);
echo json_encode(array("error"=>0,"rmb"=>$retrievermb,"title"=>$retrievetitle));
}
function retrievechTitle($htmlcode){
$html = str_get_html($htmlcode);
$title = $html->find('div[class=tb-detail-hd]h3');
return $title[0];
}
function retrievechRMB($htmlcode){
$html = str_get_html($htmlcode);
$rmb = $html->find('[class=tb-rmb-num]');
return $rmb[0];
}

?>
```

I'm trying to extract data from a HTML file, the other extraction works fine, except for the above, giving lots of issue. I even separated this set of code specifically to one PHP file for processing and same issue.

Any idea? I use jQuery Ajax with multiple functions at home page with `$.ajax({`
I'm new to Ajax, it's alright to have multiple Ajax in one page right?

Comment: Can you paste the code in `simple_html_dom.php`

Comment: It's too big to upload, it will spam the question space. Anyway it's the default file of simple html parser at sourceforge

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem clearly lies in your attempting to call `json_encode` on something not suited for it:

```
echo json_encode(array("error"=>0,"rmb"=>$retrievermb,"title"=>$retrievetitle));
```

What, we may ask, is `$retrievetitle`? What kind of value is it? Well, we find it in the function definition:

```
$html = str_get_html($htmlcode);
$title = $html->find('div[class=tb-detail-hd]h3');
return $title[0];
```

So clearly it is some kind of object. I'm not familiar with the `simple_html_dom` library, but presumably it's an object that belongs to that library and represents an HTML element.  Perhaps it is a native `DOMElement` object; I don't know.

What is clear, however, is that it is some kind of recursive structure. That is to say, in some sense it contains itself. This is perfectly possible in PHP, but it is impossible to represent in a JSON string. For instance, in PHP:

```
class Foo {
    public $self;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->self = $this;
    }
}
$foo = new Foo;
```

`$foo->self` is the same object as `$foo`. Indeed, you could do `$foo->self->self->self` and it would work fine. This is a very simple recursive structure. Yours is probably a bit more complex, but not dissimilar in principle. This can't be represented in JSON. `json_encode` will error when it encounters recursion.

I imagine you probably wanted to store the text content of the title, rather than the title element itself. Briefly reading the [API documentation for the library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm), it seems you want the `plaintext` property. I'm not quite sure how this works (the APi is, shall we say, sparse) but my guess would be the following:

```
return $title[0]->plaintext;
```

But that is only an educated guess.

Comment: Hi, ->plaintext does remove the error,  i think i know what you mean. Thanks

Comment: Let me continue reading it to try understand it :x Thank you so much lonesomeday. Thank you.

Comment: More than glad to have helped.

Answer (score 6):

Simple example to re-create the problem

```
<?php
$o = new StdClass;
$o->arr = array();
$o->arr[] = $o;

json_encode($o);
```

Once json_encode() encounters $o->arr[0]==$o it would have to start again with $o, reach $o->arr[0], start again with $o and so on ad infinitum. To prevent this, the function "remembers" each node it already processed. If it "sees" the same node again it throws the recursion warning.
The simple_html_dom objects you return from your functions probably have reference to their parents objects or something like that, causing the recursion.
So, *maybe* `return (string)$title[0];` and `return (string)$rmb[0];` will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish, using a POST method to send HTML source. Then parsing it on the server side is a bit over-kill.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST['type']) && $_REQUEST['type'] = "getmoredetails"){ 
    >> echo $_REQUEST['htmlsource'];
    >> return;
    retrievemore($_REQUEST['htmlsource']);
}

function retrievemore($htmlcode){
    $retrievetitle = retrievechTitle($htmlcode);
    $retrievermb = retrievechRMB($htmlcode);
    >> gettype($retrievetitle) . ' – ' . gettype($retrievermb);
    >> return;
    echo json_encode(array("error"=>0,"rmb"=>$retrievermb,"title"=>$retrievetitle));
}

function retrievechTitle($htmlcode){
   $html = str_get_html($htmlcode);
   $title = $html->find('div[class=tb-detail-hd]h3');
   return $title[0];
}
function retrievechRMB($htmlcode){
   $html = str_get_html($htmlcode);
   $rmb = $html->find('[class=tb-rmb-num]');
   return $rmb[0];
}

?>
```

What does your AJAX call look like? Did you set the type parameter to “POST”?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/echo/json/",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function(json)
    console.log(json);
});
```

also you should try just calling the json_encode() function by itself. see if you get an error.

```
echo json_encode(array("error"=>0,"rmb"=>"rmb","title"=>"title"));
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, Ajax, and Yes using POST. lonesomeday had a great explanation as above. Fix. Thank you for helping. Nevertheless, WELCOME TO STACKOVERFLOW!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes simple_html_dom.php won't cast to string as expected.
I've solved problem by cast string syntax:

```
$HTML_DOM = new simple_html_dom();
$HTML_DOM->load($HTML_Template,true,false); // Preserve line breaks
$Content_Box_Data = $HTML_DOM->find('div.Content_Box_Data',0); // find() 
$Content_Box_Data->innertext = "Some Content";
$HTML_Template = (string)$HTML_DOM;
```