# Symfony2 Form why my form return warning: json_encode(): recursion detected?

Tags: php, forms, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to entities, Applications and Votes.

The idea is to relate many to one. So Applications have many Votes and one Vote is for one Application.

In my entities class I have settings like this:

Application Entity Class:

```
\/**
\* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vote", mappedBy="application")
\*/
\private $votes;
```

Vote  Entity Class:

```
\/**
\* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application", inversedBy="votes")
\* @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
\*/
\private $application;
```

I think this relation is set up well or am I mistaken ?

Next thing is that I have a form builder class for only one field:

```
$builder->add('rate')
    ->add('save', 'submit');
```

The Votes entity has fields: `(id, username, rate, createdAt, updatedAt, application)`

and in my controller I'm doing something like this:

```
    $vote = new Vote();
    $form = $this->createForm(new VoteType(), $vote);

    $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $vote->setUserName($tenant->getUsername());
        $vote->setApplication($app);
        $em->persist($vote);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Oceniono aplikację.');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('applications_main'));
    }

    return array( 'form' => $form->createView(), );
```

and it isn't working, it returns me error:

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: json_encode(): recursion detected in E:\wamp\www\project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse.php line 92
```

stack trace (plain text): http://pastebin.com/bSQTDJQY

Comment: This doesn't look related the relation.  Why is json_encode being invoked?  are you encoding your response?

Comment: nope what you see is almost full controller method im only creating $app before yet

Comment: `E:\wamp\www\project\src\project\ApiBundle\EventListener\ViewListener.php line 49` your problem lays within.

Comment: `/**
     * @Observe("kernel.view", priority = -200)
     */
    public function onKernelView(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        $result = $event->getControllerResult();

        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData($result);

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }` but why it isnt working here and other forms works great ?
line49 : `$response->setData($result);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [json\_encode giving recursion error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235683/json-encode-giving-recursion-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities are prone to recursive issues, if you `var_dump` or `print_r` an entitiy, it will hang.

One of the best serialization tools that is capable of turning an entity into a hierarchal non-recursive tree is: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle

It is used with FOSRestBundle as part of its transparent acceptable response handing.

You are having a similar issue to this: [Avoiding recursion with Doctrine entities and JMSserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851197/avoiding-recursion-with-doctrine-entities-and-jmsserializer)

Check out the solution, and try using JMSSerializer.

**Edit: Other likely cause:**

When you return the `array` you are returning the form contained within that array.
Your event listener is trying to serialize this as json, this is both a cause of issues as well as being relatively pointless unless the form is being used to provide an augmented data template.

Either way, a form cannot be serialized so simply, did you even mean to do that?

Comment: so the problem is that my application entity is also related many to many with categoried entity ?

Comment: Perhaps, if that is another relation.  My first comment is probably incorrect, basic serializers aren't that clever, you need to tell it when to stop.

Comment: but my form to add category works fine, also form for adding aplciation with category works fine, and all looks similar. i dont have to (when adding vote) create relation or do i have to ?
cant i just creat vote entity by form and maybe in the future related it with some application ? im not looking in there for any apps of my vote.

Comment: Ohhh man i fixed it. thanks for your help a lot. but the problem was i was missong `@Template` statement in my controller action annotations.

Comment: **1 upvote** for me mentioning, that a form can't be serialiszed. Had one in my data array by accident.